# Writing unit test for a flask application using unittest

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I am new to unit testing and I am trying to write a test for the code I wrote which is a commenting system that saves comments and some extra information to a database. Here is the code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():

    if request.method == "POST":
        ip_address = request.remote_addr
        entry_content = request.form.get("content")
        formatted_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M")
        app.db.entries.insert({
            "content": entry_content, 
            "date": formatted_date, 
            "IP": ip_address})

    return "GET method called"
```

I want to write a test to check the `POST` part of it, but I don't know how to pass content in `POST` method and make sure everything is OK.

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

I took a look at your file. I wonder if there is a problem with your code which is that whatever method you requested it with, it will **ALWAYS** return "GET method called". Perhaps you may want to change your code to something like this:

```py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():

    if request.method == "POST":
        ip_address = request.remote_addr
        entry_content = request.form.get("content")
        formatted_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M")
        app.db.entries.insert({"content": entry_content, "date": formatted_date, "IP": ip_address})
        return "POST method called"

    return "GET method called"
```

First create a file named `test_app.py` and make sure there **isn't** an `__init__.py` in your directory.

`test_app.py` should contain codes listed below:

```py
import unittest

from app import app

class AppTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.ctx = app.app_context()
        self.ctx.push()
        self.client = app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.ctx.pop()

    def test_home(self):
        response = self.client.post("/", data={"content": "hello world"})
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert "POST method called" == response.get_data(as_text=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Open your terminal and `cd` to your directory then run `python3 app.py`. If you are using windows then run `python app.py` instead.

Hope this will help you solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it but I am getting below error:
[2021-11-08 10:56:07,700] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    rv = self.dispatch_request()

Comment: By the way I am using mongodb cloud for my database

Comment: Could you give your full error output? I can't figure out the exception type from the error message you give :(

Comment: https://ctxt.io/2/AABg3tHDEw

Comment: I'm sorry that unfortunately the link expired :( Would you please re-generate one?

Comment: Here is the new one. sorry about that
https://ctxt.io/2/AABgqtnrFw

Comment: Why should he not put an __init__.py file in his testing folder?

Comment: @AhmedAlhallag I put `test_app.py` along side `app.py`. And I write `from app import app` in my code, if there's a `__init__.py` then it should be `from .app from app` instead. If the tests lie in a standalone folder, then putting an `__init__.py` is okay.